# Why after adding proxyPort in wso2 api manager 3.2.0, can not accsess directly to https://api.am.wso2.com:443/publisher?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to use Nginx revers proxy as load balancer, but after adding proxyPort in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 deployment.toml :

```
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

I can not accsess directly to  https://api.am.wso2.com:443/publisher?

Also my hostname = "api.am.wso2.com"

cloud please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `proxyPort` is enabled, you need to at least have an Nginx instance running with the relative configurations to access the API Manager. You can find the default Single node Nginx configurations in [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#step-2-configure-the-load-balancerreverse-proxy-server).

Therefore, this is expected behavior. As an alternate, you can disable the Proxy Port configurations and only configure the Hostname in the TOML and try accessing the portals.

Comment: Thanks, why we set proxyport to 443, but in nginx config we set server address port to 9443. I mean in deployment.toml proxyPort=443 & in nginx server 172.24.64.114:9443?

Comment: We configure the underlying Tomcat server to respond to the client using 443 and not 9443. We are basically saying that to communicate with a Proxy using this port (443), internally everything goes with 9443. You can learn more about Tomcat's Proxy support and configurations in [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Proxy_Support). So, the Nginx will be receiving and responding with 443 whereas the internal Proxy communications are made through 9443.